# autoconf: AC_PROG_CC checks for object and executable suffix, but how to get this?

Tags: gnu, autoconf

I'm a newbie to autoconf, and found out that a call of the macro `AC_PROG_CC` checks for the suffixes of executables and object files. Now I want to use the results of these checks and replace them in my `Makefile.in`, but there is no adequate documentation or mentioning in the autoconf docs on how to use this.

I'm also having the general problem: Which macro gives me which variables, and where is a reference to get know about?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables you are looking for are `@EXEEXT@` and `@OBJEXT@`.

[This link](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/Output-Variable-Index.html#Output-Variable-Index) takes you to the index of all the output variables from the Autoconf manual.

Unfortunately there's no easy table of which ones are defined by which macros, you just have to read the descriptions.